# Eclipse 3.6: Can't find Git support

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-3.6, egit

I just installed Eclipse 3.6 Helios, which is supposed to offer integrated Git support, but I just can't find any related view or perspective. I installed Eclipse for JavaEE for Linux 32 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VCS plugins are in the "Team" submenu of the project context menu. See the [user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

Comment: OK, that's exactly hat I wanted to know. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Eclipse for JavaEE does not contain the git suppport 'out-of-the-box'. You have to install the E-Git plugin from [their update site](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/). After installing it you should read the user guide wRAR mentioned in his answer.